# How to extract json Response in rest assured with points in key

Tags: java, json, http, rest-assured

To extract status form this response in rest assured i just need to use `one.response` or `two.response`

```
{
"one": {
    "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
    "fileNum": "1"
},
"two": {
    "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
    "fileNum": "2"
}}
```

But how can I extract the same value (without changing key) if i have such response:

```
{
"something.one.txt": {
    "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
    "fileNum": "1"
},
"somethinganother.two.txt": {
    "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
    "fileNum": "2"
}}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using **one.response** in Java? If yes which library are you using?

Comment: yes, rest assured  `response.jsonPath().get("one.response")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the key:

```
response.jsonPath().getString("'something.one.txt'.status") // Will return "SUCCESSFUL"
```